# How to insert an html input array into mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an HTML form that has 2 dynamic fields which are:

```
<input type="text"  name="ingredients[]" placeholder="Ingredients"/></div>
<input type="text"  name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity"/></div>
```

Look here this is how the db table should be for those inputs in the form
Ing 1   1001  1KG
Ing 2   1001  2KG
ing 3   1001  3KG

now check the image and you'll see what's happening

[DB Ingredients TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhL1F.png)

I have the recipe-ID in my php file I just want a PDO code that help me to INSERT "ingredients", "quantity" and "$recipe_ID" each one on a row.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once 'db/pdoconnect.php';
if($_POST)
    {

        $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT `recipeid` FROM Recipes ORDER BY `recipeid` DESC");
        $sth->execute();
        $previousid = $sth->fetchColumn();
        $offset=1;
        $generatingid=$previousid+$offset;
        $newid=$generatingid;
        //print("Last Id=$previousid\n");
        //print("New Id=$newid\n");

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $preptime = $_POST['preptime'];
        $cocktime = $_POST['cocktime'];
        $level = $_POST['level'];
        $serving = $_POST['serving'];
        $recipetype = $_POST['recipetype'];
        $intro = $_POST['intro'];
        $details = $_POST['details'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];

        try
        {    

            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Recipes (recipeid,title,preptime,cocktime,level,serving,recipetype,intro,details,recipeimg) VALUES( :newid, :title, :preptime, :cocktime, :level, :serving, :recipetype, :intro, :details, :image)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":newid",$newid);
            $stmt->bindParam(":title",$title);
            $stmt->bindParam(":preptime",$preptime);
            $stmt->bindParam(":cocktime",$cocktime);
            $stmt->bindParam(":level",$level);
            $stmt->bindParam(":serving",$serving);
            $stmt->bindParam(":recipetype",$recipetype);
            $stmt->bindParam(":intro",$intro);
            $stmt->bindParam(":details",$details);
            $stmt->bindParam(":image",$image);

               if($stmt->execute()) { //check if main query has been executed 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $sql .= " (:recipeid" .$i. ", :ingredient" .$i. ", :quantity" .$i. "),"; 
    }

    // remove the last (,) from the $sql
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sth = $con->prepare($sql);

    // binding parameters 
    for($i = 1 ; $i <= count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $varIng = $_POST['ingredients'][$i];
        $varQnty = $_POST['quantity'][$i];

        $sth->bindParam(':recipeid' .$i , $newid , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':ingredient' .$i , $varIng , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':quantity' .$i , $varQnty , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }  
              if ($sth->execute()) { 
              $response_array['status'] = 'success';  
                  }
              }//END OF FIRST IF STATEMENT

              else{
              $response_array['status'] = 'error';  
              }
               echo json_encode($response_array);   //SEND THE RESPONSE

               }//END OF TRY 

        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: that's nice, so did you have a question?

Comment: I need to know how to do it?

Comment: the query you're using or tried to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table's name shown in the image you posted in your question `ingredient_quantity` in your database, and you said you already have the `recipe-ID`  [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ikwr-n44f)

```
<?php 
    $newid = 'A10';
    //considering this is your table shown in the picture
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ingredient_quantity VALUES";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $sql .= " (:newid" .$i. ", :ingredient" .$i. ", :quantity" .$i. "),"; 
    }

    // remove the last (,) from the $sql
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sth = $con->prepare($sql);

    // binding parameters 
    for($i = 1 ; $i <= count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $varIng = $_POST['ingredients'][$i];
        $varQnty = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
        $sth->bindParam(':newid' .$i , $newid , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':ingredient' .$i , $varIng , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':quantity' .$i , $varQnty , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $sth->execute();
?>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

for the above code I have an error as the `ingredients[]` array starts from `0` and not `1`, the final `index` of the `for` loop will be `undefined`, so work around it make the last `for` loop like the following:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $varIng = $_POST['ingredients'][$i];
        $varQnty = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
        $j = $i + 1;
        $sth->bindParam(':newid' .$j , $newid , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':ingredient' .$j , $varIng , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':quantity' .$j , $varQnty , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
You may try doing it with `?` placeholders instead of named placeholders like this [**PHP Fiddle 2**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7esk-py4h):

```
//considering this is your table shown in the picture
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ingredient_quantity VALUES";

    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $sql .= " ( ? , ? , ? ) , "; 
    }

    // remove the last (,) from the $sql
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $sth = $con->prepare($sql);

    // binding parameters 
    $j = 1;
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_POST['ingredients']) ; $i++){
        $varIng = $_POST['ingredients'][$i];
        $varQnty = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
        $sth->bindValue( $j , $varIng);
        $sth->bindValue( $j + 1, $newid);
        $sth->bindValue( $j + 2, $varQnty);
        $j += 3;
    }
    $sth->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I need to insert the recipe_id with this query also could you please tell me where to put it ??? thanks

Comment: the code snippet above is for inserting values into the table in your image, according to your code in the question i think you need to put this after `if($stmt->execute()) { // returns true on success`

Comment: yes the recipe_Id is not on the database I have it inside my php file as $recipe_id and I need to put it together with the ingredients and quantity

Comment: for the `recipe_id` i am not sure where are you getting it from, is it same as `$newid` ?

Comment: Hello Mi-Creativity I added to the first line the following:$sql = "INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES (recipe_id, ingredients, quantity)"; IT SAVES THE $newid or recipe id but for the ingredients and quantity it keeps saving NULL !!! could you please help me

Comment: the `$sql` before the two `for` loops must end with the word `VALUES`, don't put anything after it because the first `for` loop will construct the complete `SQL` statement, the second `for` loop is responsible for binding the values, your first line must be the following: `INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES ` and no more

Comment: I added your code but there something wrong please check the question I updated the question with your code

Comment: the first query which insert value inside RECIPE table is working but the other query that insert value inside INGREDIENTS table is giving me SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 THE TABLE EXACT ORDER IS: INGREDIENT - RECIPEID - QUANTITY but even If I switch the code to put recipeid first it doesn't work

Comment: `THE TABLE EXACT ORDER IS: INGREDIENT - RECIPEID - QUANTITY` you need to make sure the items in the `sql` are in the same order also the column count must be the same

Comment: okey I correct the order and the error has gone but look at the image above they still saving NULL no values inside ingredient and quantity!!

Comment: what if you write them like this `$sth->bindParam(':ingredient' .$i , $varIng);
        $sth->bindParam(':quantity' .$i , $varQnty);` instead?

Comment: the update you gave to the first code is awesome it works fine ... but the only problem is in the Form when the user add another ingredient input field the database is saving all the ingredient fields with last value of ingredient in the form and discard the previous ones

Comment: You mean the answer in `EDIT 1` or `EDIT 2`?

Comment: no EDIT 1 the updated one save everything in right order but in the form if the user wants to add another ingredient field let say he has 2 ingredients for that recipe the database is saving 2 fields as it should but both values are the ones of the last field the value of the first field is discarded I will add an image to show you

Comment: what if you insert 3 or 4 ingredients?

Comment: yes that's what am trying to do... the user can add as many ingredients as he needs but the code is just saving the last one in all the fields check the image in the question

Comment: what if you try the answer in `EDIT 2`? the problem is your question has lots of dependencies to reproduce the bug this why i am just resolving it theoretically

Comment: In EDIT 2 it works fine for additional input fields and save data correctly but there's a small problem that is: the $newid is appearing in the ingredient column in the DB and the $ingredient is appearing in the recipeid column in the db is there a way to switch them and make them correct?

Comment: sure that's so easy to fix, just switch `$newid` and `$varIng` places in the `bindValue` statements

Comment: so it becomes `$sth->bindValue( $j , $varIng);
        $sth->bindValue( $j + 1, $newid);
        $sth->bindValue( $j + 2, $varQnty);`

Comment: BRO YOUR A KING THANK YOU NOW EVERYTHING IS WORKING AWESOME. THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH